# asp.net mvc internal server error after post

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

When I submit a form with validation errors back I do

```
return View(model);
```

What I get to see in the browser is the raw html, instead of the normal page. With fiddler, I find out that the contenttype of the response has all of a sudden become "application/json" and I see "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error".

In the global.asax I hav put:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        var errors = this.Context.AllErrors;
    }
```

And errors is null. So I have no idea how to find out what the error is.

Comment: Check your request content type in fiddler. Is it asking for a json response or HTML??

Comment: no, it is asking for html

Comment: what is the return type on the post method?

Comment: that's the problem: the return type is "application/json"